# IIS tries to connect to a database as a non existent user

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2008

On my webserver i had old asp.net mvc application which was working perfectly, but i decided to remove it.
Now i installed the new one, and i get the following error when i try to open my website:

```
Cannot open database "MyDbName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.
```

The problem is, that i do not have user called 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' in my system. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Check the identity on the web site's application pool. That is where this account is being set.

Also, that account is available on your machine, it is built in. On the permissions dialog just type "Network service" and then it will resolve to that account.

Comment: In what permissions dialog? In my database i dont have anything like that, also, i don't know if i should be editing users or roles in my sql management studio?

Comment: You should be adding accounts in SSMS to the DB